# Covariance of a binomial random variable in an urn problem

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, covariance

> An urn contains $100$ blue balls, $100$ yellow balls, $100$ orange balls, $100$ green balls and $100$ red balls. $60$ balls are picked (with replacement) from the urn at random. Let $$ be the number of times a red ball was picked, and let $$ be the
> number of times a green ball was picked.

The question is split into two parts.

> a. What is the joint density of (, )?
>
> b. What is Cov($X,Y$)?

I thought I'd do something like this.

For part (a) $$
\left(x,y\right)\:=\:\frac{60!}{x!y!\left(60-x-y\right)!}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{x+y}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{60-x-y}$$

And for part (b)

$$
cov\left(X,Y\right)\:=\:cov\left(X,60-X\right)=cov\left(X,60\right)+cov\left(X,-X\right)$$
$$=0\:-cov\left(X,X\right)\:=\:-var\left(X\right)=0.96
$$
using this:
$$
cov\left(X,60\right)\:=E\left[60X\right]-\:E\left[60\right]E\left[X\right]=60E\left[X\right]-60E\left[X\right]=0
$$
and the fact that X+Y should be equal to 60.

But **the answer is**:
, ~(60, 1/5) and +~(60, 2/5)
$$
cov\left(X,Y\right)=\:\frac{var\left(X+Y\right)-var\left(X\right)-var\left(Y\right)}{2}=\frac{60\cdot \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{4}{5}-2\cdot 60\cdot \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{4}{5}}{2}=-2.4
$$

Can someone help me understand why my method doesn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is $cov(X,Y)=cov(X,60-X)$?

Comment: because X+Y should be equal to 60

Comment: That's only true if no orange or yellow balls are picked

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As discussed in the comments, $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=\operatorname{cov}(X-60-X)$ would hold only if only red and green balls could be picked, no orange or yellow balls.